# ErrorException [Notice]:Array to string conversion PHP Form

Tags: php, database, forms, kohana

I am creating a very simple form to collect data from a user and store in a database, but i am getting an error:

> **ErrorException [Notice]: Array to string conversion**
>   SYSPATH\classes\kohana\html.php

I have used this code before in another one of my forms and i have never had any problems, maybe i am missing something?

```
<div id="formWrapper">
 <?php
{
         echo form::open('', array('id'=>'newprefecture'));

         echo form::label('NewPrefecture', 'prefecture:');
         echo form::input('form[NewPrefecture]', array('class'=>'input', 'id'=>'NewPrefecture'));

         echo form::submit('btnSubmit', 'Submit', array('id'=>'btnSubmit', 'class'=>'button'));
         echo form::close();
}
         ?>
         </div>


public function action_newprefecture(){
          $this->template->content = View::factory('admin/main-menu');
          $this->template->content->val = '';
    $this->template->content->post = '';

    if ($this->request->post('form')) {
                                    $post = $this->request->post('form');
    $stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `prefectures` (`prefecture`)
                                                          VALUES (:NewPrefecture)'); 
          $stmt->param(':NewPrefecture', $post['NewPrefecture']);
          try {
                                                $stmt->execute();
                                                $this->template->content->post = $post;
                                                $this->template->content->thanks = true;
                                                } catch (Exception $e) {
                                                    FB::error($e);
                                                }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: The error should point to a specific line in your code - which is it?

Comment: 1) It's not an error, it's a notice, and it simply means that you're passing an array to a function that tries to `echo` that array as though it were a string. 2) properly indent/format your code 3) add the line number that is in your notice 4) avoid static methods whenever/wherever you can

Comment: Line 66 - return htmlspecialchars( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, Kohana::$charset, $double_encode);

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might need to add a default value (or NULL) to your input right before the attributes, like this:

```
echo form::input('form[NewPrefecture]', NULL, array('class'=>'input', 'id'=>'NewPrefecture'));
```

http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Form#input